# mysql_query returning value as 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
$img_id = mysql_query("SELECT img_id FROM img_path where ul_id = $ul_id ");     
$img_id = $img_id[0];
```

`$img_id` at end is output as 0, I want the value that is stored for `img_id` in the table `img_path`.

I have checked the database connections and they are fine. Any help?

Comment: You need to fetch results from queried object in `$img_id` you have a queried object not results from query

Comment: Could you please provide me the correct code as per your explanation?

Comment: mysql_* functions are obsolete and deprecated. Please, have a look at http://php.net/mysqli and http://php.net/pdo. In your case query result should be fetched with mysql_fetch_* befode usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$img_id` contains a [**result resource**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) that is returned by [**mysql_query**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

To get the query result you have to fetch it with one of the mysql_fetch_* functions, [**mysql_fetch_array**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), i.e.

Also, for security reasons you should always escape your variables passed to the query.

But as [**mysql**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is deprecated you should better use [**mysqli**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**pdo**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**Anyway, this is how you do it with mysql:**

```
$ul_id = mysql_real_escape_string($ul_id);
$img_id = mysql_query("SELECT img_id FROM img_path where ul_id = $ul_id ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($img_id)
$img_id = $row['img_id']; // access through associative indices or
// $img_id = $row[0]; // access through number indices
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code. You need to fetch the record

```
$img_id = mysql_query("SELECT img_id FROM img_path where ul_id = $ul_id "); 

$imgID = mysql_fetch_array($img_id);

$img_id1 = $imgID['img_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$ul_id = mysql_real_escape_string($ul_id);
$img_id =mysql_query("SELECT img_id FROM img_path where ul_id = '".$ul_id."' "); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($img_id);
$img = $row['img_id'];
```

or if you looking for fetch_row

then use this:

```
$ul_id = mysql_real_escape_string($ul_id);
$img_id =mysql_query("SELECT img_id FROM img_path where ul_id = '".$ul_id."' "); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($img_id);
$img = $row[0];
```

---

- consider to change to MYSQLI or PDO as mysql is deprecated.
- consider to escape your variables.